# Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)

Tags: vue.js, webpack

[image: error]

`package.json`

`{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "HTML template",
  "main": "src/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "watch": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
    "build": "webpack --mode production && prettier --print-width=120 --parser html --write dist/*.html"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "js-beautify": "^1.10.2",
    "less-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "parse": "^2.11.0",
    "parser": "^0.1.4",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-cookie": "^1.1.4",
    "vue-footer": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-headful": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-loader": "^15.8.3",
    "vue-moment": "^4.1.0",
    "vue-resource": "^1.5.1",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.3",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.2",
    "vue-tabs-with-active-line": "^1.2.5",
    "vue-tel-input": "^4.1.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-the-mask": "^0.11.1",
    "vuejs": "^3.0.1",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.0",
    "cssnano": "^4.1.10",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.1",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.1"
  }
}`

`webpack.config.js`

```
    const path = require("path");
    const fs = require("fs");
    const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
    const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
    const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
    const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
    const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
    function generateHtmlPlugins(templateDir) {
      const templateFiles = fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, templateDir));
      return templateFiles.map(item => {
        const parts = item.split(".");
        const name = parts[0];
        const extension = parts[1];
        return new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          filename: `${name}.html`,
          template: path.resolve(__dirname, `${templateDir}/${name}.${extension}`),
          inject: false
        });
      });
    }
    const htmlPlugins = generateHtmlPlugins("./src/html/views");
    const config = {
      entry: ["./src/main.js", "./static/css/app.10c9cba5f2e2f1dc959b0a7520f19d0b.css"],
      output: {
        filename: "./js/bundle.js"
      },
      devtool: "source-map",
      mode: "production",
      optimization: {
        minimizer: [
          new TerserPlugin({
            sourceMap: true,
            extractComments: true
          })
        ]
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            include: path.resolve(__dirname, "./static/css"),
            use: [
              {
                loader: 'style-loader',
                options: {}
              },
              {
                loader: "css-loader",
                options: {
                  sourceMap: true,
                  url: false
                }
              },
              {
                loader: "postcss-loader",
                options: {
                  ident: "postcss",
                  sourceMap: true,
                  plugins: () => [
                    require("cssnano")({
                      preset: [
                        "default",
                        {
                          discardComments: {
                            removeAll: true
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    })
                  ]
                }
              },
    {
                loader: "sass-loader",
                options: {
                  sourceMap: true
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
            include: path.resolve(__dirname, "./static/fonts"),
            use: ["vue-loader"]
          }
        ]
      },
      plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
          filename: "./static/css/app.10c9cba5f2e2f1dc959b0a7520f19d0b.css"
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
          {
            from: "/dev/App/webpack/src/components/template/Site-bottom.vue",       
          },
          {
            from: "/dev/App/webpack/src/components/template/Site-top.vue",      
          },
          {
            from: "./node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin",
            to: "./img"
          },
          {
            from: "./src/uploads",
            to: "./uploads"
          }
        ])
      ].concat(htmlPlugins)
    };
    module.exports = (env, argv) => {
      if (argv.mode === "production") {
        config.plugins.push(new CleanWebpackPlugin());
      }
      return config;
    };
```

Comment: Настрой по-человечески Webpack... Даже без спецзнаний очевидно, что нелогично применение загрузчика vue-файлов к файлам шрифтов.

Comment: Спасибо за совет я не подгрузил yarn, как мне это сделать и я думаю, что webpack.config js не правильно прописан

Comment: Так да, неправильно. Вот смотри: тебе в ошибке webpack пишет что не понимает vue-файл, и ему нужен загрузчик такого типа файлов. Загрузчиком для них является `vue-loader`. Он у тебя есть, но в конфиге почему-то используется для загрузки файлов шрифтов. Посмотри документацию этого загрузчика: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/ru/guide/

Answer (score 0):

`конфиг редактировал, вот, что получилось`

```
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
function generateHtmlPlugins(templateDir) {
  const templateFiles = fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, templateDir));
  return templateFiles.map(item => {
    const parts = item.split(".");
    const name = parts[0];
    const extension = parts[1];
    return new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: `${name}.html`,
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, `${templateDir}/${name}.${extension}`),
      inject: false
    });
  });
}
const htmlPlugins = generateHtmlPlugins("./src/html/views");
const config = {
  entry: ["./src/main.js"],
  output: {
    filename: "./js/bundle.js"
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  mode: "production",
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        sourceMap: true,
        extractComments: true
      })
    ]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [

      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/"),
        use: [

          {
            loader: 'vue-loader',
            options: {

                 }
          },


          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              url: false
            }
          },
          {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
            options: {
              ident: "postcss",
              sourceMap: true,
              plugins: () => [
                require("cssnano")({
                  preset: [
                    "default",
                    {
                      discardComments: {
                        removeAll: true
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                })
              ]
            }
          },
{
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "./static/fonts"),
        use: ["vue-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },


  plugins: [
      new VueLoaderPlugin({
  filename: "./node_modules/vue-loader"
}),


    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "./static/css/app.10c9cba5f2e2f1dc959b0a7520f19d0b.css"
    }),

  ].concat(htmlPlugins)
};
module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  if (argv.mode === "production") {
    config.plugins.push(new CleanWebpackPlugin());
  }
  return config;
};
```

`и теперь такая ошибка :`

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module './lib/loader'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:571:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:497:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/dev/App/webpack/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js:1:80)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:678:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at loadLoader (/dev/App/webpack/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:18:17)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/dev/App/webpack/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at runLoaders (/dev/App/webpack/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:365:2)
    at NormalModule.doBuild (/dev/App/webpack/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:295:3)
 @ ./src/main.js 2:0-28 34:16-19
 @ multi ./src/main.js
```

Answer (score 0):

после этой ошибки прописал npm install vue-loader
тем самым переустановил его и в итоге опять ошибка по конфигу

ERROR in ./src/App.vue
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Invalid CSS after "<": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was ""
        on line 1 of /dev/App/webpack/src/App.vue

> > 

^

@ ./src/main.js 2:0-28 34:16-19
 @ multi ./src/main.js

Comment: Потому что перед тем как очередь дойдет но `vue-loader` ты кормишь `.vue`-файлы всевозможным лоудерам от sccs до style, которые не умеют работать с этим типом файлов и валятся на первой же `<` в `<template>`